# What version of DotA where there is a secret quest/mission?

Tags: dota

There was a version of **DotA** where you collect some sort of `icefrogs` with letters or something then after collecting those, you get to fight a hero that some sort of boss since that hero has a huge amount of HP.

What version of **DotA** has this hidden game sidequest?

Also, how to start that hidden sidequest?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

versions `*.*9` has hidden quests, but I don't know which version was first to introduce this feature.

[6.49 version hidden quest with icefrogs](http://www.dota-blog.com/2007/11/649-dota-allstars-map-secret-boss-frog.html)

[6.59b version hidden quest with Taurean Chieftain](http://www.dota-blog.com/2008/11/dota-659b-quest-dota-allstars-659b-side.html)

[6.69 version hidden quest with Phoenix](http://www.neutralcreeps.com/2010/10/dota-669-quest-phoenix-secret-mission.html)

Comment: What version exactly is `*.*9`. Also how do I start the sidequest?

Comment: simple google search will give you all needed answers https://www.google.com/search?q=hidden+dota+boss+quests

Comment: And about icefrogs, it's a 6.49 version. http://www.dota-blog.com/2007/11/649-dota-allstars-map-secret-boss-frog.html

Comment: @MadCom Arqade is supposed to be acting as the definitive resource for gaming questions and answers, the first thing that should appear on Google when querying for information. As a result, you should try to use your answer to pool together as much relevant information as possible instead of redirecting the user on another Google search. Could you edit your answer to include the information on how to start the quest?

Comment: Also, regular expressions aren't very clear to most people. Did you mean any version that ends in a 9?